# UserId is null in Interceptor postHandle method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak, interceptor

I have added a interceptor to get the logged in user id and persist in log with the help of MDC.
But I am getting NullPointerException at the line
"String userid = userDetailUtil.getUserId();" // NullPointerException

userDetailUtil.getUserId(); // This is the Keycloak user details

[image]

I am trying to get the same userid in controller class . I am getting the logged in userid value in the controller. Its working fine.

[image]

Can someone help why the userid in null in the interceptor postHandle() method alone.
Even I tried using preHandle and afterCompletion method and getting the NullPointerException

Comment: consider adding if you don't already have it  `@Component` in the UserDetailUtil

Answer (score 0):

*I am getting NullPointerException at the line "String userid = userDetailUtil.getUserId();* **and** *Can someone help why the userid in null in the interceptor postHandle() method alone.*// NullPointerException*

Getting a Nullpointer exception at the mentioned line does not necessarily mean that the userId is null! It can easily happen that the userDetailUtil itself is not injected, the userDetailUtil is null, hence the expection. Check this in debug mode.

If this is the case, consider using a servlet filter instead, it may be more suitable for your task, and filters are generally more powerful than interceptors.

If the userDetailUtil is injected correctly, then you should give more information about your userDetails logic. The root of the problem can be that the interceptor runs before the security logic and that's why there is no userId yet.